# Why some functions need to be injected as DLL files to work

Tags: c++, windows, memory, dll, inject

So I've been learning C++ lately and there was this part I couldn't I understand, I saw someone use this function in a dll file that he injected :

```
void WriteToMemory(DWORD AddressToWrite, char* ValueToWrite, int byteNum){
unsigned long oldProtection;
VirtualProtect((LPVOID)AddressToWrite, byteNum, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtection);memcpy((LPVOID)AddressToWrite, ValueToWrite, byteNum);

VirtualProtect((LPVOID)AddressToWrite, byteNum, oldProtection, NULL);}
```

But when I try this function whit a normal script my program keeps crushing , so why does it need to be injected first and what's the point of injecting DLL files?

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++, really. DLL injection requires a good knowledge of Windows process and memory architecture. Perhaps another project would be better to start, like writing a notepad clone?

Comment: There's no obvious reason why that code would crash, you're probably just calling it incorrectly.  On the other hand, it's hard to imagine what you would be using it for in the first place.

Comment: well I'm using it to change A game's  Opcodes values, In first I tried using the WriteProcessMemory() function but it didn't work then I saw this dude using memcpy() and it worked for him but he had to inject a DLL file first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`memcpy` is a function meant to be used on memory that you own and only that. It will only work in the current process in which it's called.

Each process has its own memory. One process can allocate something at 0x14141 and another can allocate at 0x14141 and it won't clash because the address is local to that process. `memcpy` works the same way. It copies to the address of the current process and won't affect memory in other processes.

When you attempt to use it on memory owned by another process, it will crash if the memory isn't shared/mapped. It will actually be copying to that address of your current process and not the other process.

On the other hand, `WriteProcessMemory` will work on memory belonging to other processes provided you have the correct privileges/access-rights.

When the guy injects the module into the other process, the module is essentially part of that process now and so `memcpy` can be used. It's as if the process loaded the module itself. The module is part of the "new" current process.. aka the injected process.